# Php Contact Form

Tags: php, jquery

This is my second attempt at a php contact form using Jquery and php to validate. I am pretty happy with the jquery but am unsure if I did the php right. I looked online and combined a few tutorials. Is this the best way to go about validating the fields and making sure the sendmail function is not improperly used? Is this a good way of going about this? Is there a better? Thanks in advance.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    //Check to make sure that the name field is not empty
    if(trim($_POST['emailTo']) == '') {
        $hasError = true;
    } else {
        $name = trim($_POST['emailTo']);
    }
    //Check to make sure that the subject field is not empty
    if(trim($_POST['subject']) == '') {
        $hasError = true;
    } else {
        $subject = trim($_POST['subject']);
    }
    //Check to make sure sure that a valid email address is submitted
    if(trim($_POST['emailFrom']) == '')  {
        $hasError = true;
    } else if (!eregi("^[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9._%-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$", trim($_POST['emailFrom']))) {
        $hasError = true;
    } else {
        $email = trim($_POST['emailFrom']);
    }
    //Check to make sure comments were entered
    if(trim($_POST['message']) == '') {
        $hasError = true;
    } else {
        if(function_exists('stripslashes')) {
            $comments = stripslashes(trim($_POST['message']));
        } else {
            $comments = trim($_POST['message']);
        }
    }
    $dodgy_strings = array(
                "content-type:"
                ,"mime-version:"
                ,"multipart/mixed"
                ,"bcc:"
);

function is_valid_email($email) {
  return preg_match('#^[a-z0-9.!\#$%&\'*+-/=?^_`{|}~]+@([0-9.]+|([^\s]+\.+[a-z]{2,6}))$#si', $email);
}

function contains_bad_str($str_to_test) {
  $bad_strings = array(
                "content-type:"
                ,"mime-version:"
                ,"multipart/mixed"
        ,"Content-Transfer-Encoding:"
                ,"bcc:"
        ,"cc:"
        ,"to:"
  );

  foreach($bad_strings as $bad_string) {
    if(eregi($bad_string, strtolower($str_to_test))) {
      echo "$bad_string found. Suspected injection attempt - mail not being sent.";
      exit;
    }
  }
}

function contains_newlines($str_to_test) {
   if(preg_match("/(%0A|%0D|\\n+|\\r+)/i", $str_to_test) != 0) {
     echo "newline found in $str_to_test. Suspected injection attempt - mail not being sent.";
     exit;
   }
} 

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != "POST"){
   echo("Unauthorized attempt to access page.");
   exit;
}

if (!is_valid_email($email)) {
  echo 'Invalid email submitted - mail not being sent.';
  exit;
}

contains_bad_str($email);
contains_bad_str($subject);
contains_bad_str(body);

contains_newlines($email);
contains_newlines($subject);

    //If there is no error, send the email
    if(!isset($hasError)) {
        $emailTo = 'My@Email.com';
        $body = "Name: $name \n\nEmail: $email \n\nSubject: $subject \n\nComments:\n $comments";
        $headers = 'From: My Site <'.$emailTo.'>' . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: ' . $email;
        mail($emailTo, $subject, $body, $headers);
        $emailSent = true;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: `eregi` is a deprecated function as of PHP 5.3.0. According to the manual `Relying on this feature is highly discouraged.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very complicated (script you wrote).
Essentially you need two scripts, one for ajax and second one normal php contact form.
Lets call the first one ajax.php (both script contain sam validation rules), when user enters for example his mail (you bind jquery blur event to email) a request is sent to...

ajax.php?action=checkmail&email=example@example.com

You can then print return by email input box, eg "Your email is valid." or contrary.

You can also use only ajax.php to send mail by passing all parameters to it, and then showing user "email is sent" or "email is not sent because..." without refreshing the page.

Comment: I think this is above my head is there anyway you can show me? Also should I not be using Eregi?

Answer (score 0):

Well this is quite nice solution, a working one. I've seen much worst around.
Only a few notes.

- it has some unnecessary validations, say `contains_bad_str(body);` is useless. And whole "bad words" approach at all. Newline test is enough
- just a rule: `DO NOT TALK TO STRANGERS`. Never talk to possible attacker, providing them with any feedback. All these "Suspected injection attempt" are childish and more of it - it supply an attacker with information they can use. Always send just 500 HTTP error in all these cases and nothing else.
- you're using pretty unusual way of error handling. I can't understand the difference between these code snippets

why the first one just sets a variable

```
if(trim($_POST['emailTo']) == '') {
    $hasError = true;
```

and second one prints an error and exits?

```
if (!is_valid_email($email)) {
  echo 'Invalid email submitted - mail not being sent.';
  exit;
}
```

Will you provide a fair user with any feedback on error occurred? Something like "Please fill all required fields"?

- I wouldn't make user supplied e-mail subject but rather some hardcoded sentence, like `Feedback from ".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`. I'd like to distinguish feedback messages in my mailbox from the regular ones. (I wouldn't make that fancy reply-to feature either, but it's my own preference)
- stripslashes thing. Why only message? Aren't other fields behave the same? And at least you have check get_magic_quotes_gpc() before applying. I'd make it automated, at hte top of the script, both stripslashes and trim, just in the loop over $_POST array.

Comment: How do I redirect to 500 http?

Thats just based off the tutorial I read should it not be set as a variable and then ext is that bad practice? Can you show me a better way?

Also I dunno about the magic quotes thing can you explain how or show me an example?
Sorry I am still very noob at this

Thanks

Comment: @Jacinto not redirect. just send a 500 error using `header()` function and exit. Aside from tutorials - how do you think your form should look and behave? Just from the users point of view? Did you happen to use such a forms on the other sites? What is your own opinion? magic quotes are well explained in the manual, just google for `php magic quotes`

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest that three year old error-ridden articles from [phpbuilder.com](http://www.phpbuilder.com/columns/ian_gilfillan20060412.php3) are probably not the best source to be using to concoct your own mailer. Instead, I'd be using something more up-to-date like the validate and sanitize filters in PHP 5 SPL.

I'd also take a look at PHPMailer or some other library that will perform security checks for you.